# How to show leaflet popup content from ajax method?

Tags: ajax, popup, leaflet, marker

I am new to leaflet maps.I am trying to show some markers on map and regarding data for each marker in a popup.

This my ajax call to get latlng of markers.

```
var getLocations='/equipment/api/getLocations';
            $.ajax({
                url:getLocations,
                method:'get'
            }).done(function(response){
                var resultData = response.data.filters;
                $.each(resultData,function(i,value){
                    if((value.latitude!=0.0) || (value.longitude!=0.0)){
                        L.marker([value.latitude,value.longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Popup Content");
                    }
                })
            });
```

Here am getting latlng values and no issues in showing popup.

This is the method for getting popup data.

```
var getData='/equipment/api/getPopupData';
            $.ajax({
                url:getData,
                method:'get'
            }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response)
            })
```

Here also am getting popup data without any issues.

Now my doubt is how can I the popup data in a related marker? One more thing now I am showing the popup in `onclick` of marker but I want to show it in `onhover`.
Can anyone give me some ideas?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If i got it right, you want to **show your popup data to an specific marker** right? after the ajax response in the getPopupData, you can put the information in the bindPopup like this (it's an example):

```
var marker = new L.marker([value.latitude,value.longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<a style='font-size:18px; font-style: italic; font-family:courier; cursor: pointer;'>" + varInfoFromGetPopupData + "</a>);
```

The above one is assuming the response is only data values, if it's an HTML contruction, you can just do it like this:

```
var marker = new L.marker([value.latitude,value.longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup("'" + varInfoFromGetPopupData + "'");
```

if not, could you be more specific about it?

**And**

To get the popup to open **onhover**, you need to do it like this:

```
marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            this.openPopup();
        });
```

and to close it, you use **mouseout:**

```
marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                this.closePopup();
            });
```

i hope this helped you.

Comment: If I use this for mousehover means ,am getting an error `marker is not defined`.

Comment: i don't know if it's a typo, but it's **mouseover**, but when creating a marker, try do it like this and give me the feedback: `var marker = new L.marker([value.latitude,value.longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Popup Content");` and then, i think you can do `the marker.on()` function

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you will need a way to connect between the two data sets. The connection probably based on a field that resides both in `getLocations` and `getData` results. By running the `gatData` ajax after `getLocations` is done, you can use the locations data with the data. This code block follows the thought that both ajax results are in the same order (a poor assumption, you probably have an id in both results).

```
var getLocations='/equipment/api/getLocations';
            $.ajax({
                url:getLocations,
                method:'get'
            }).done(function(response){
                var resultData = response.data.filters;

                var getData='/equipment/api/getPopupData';
                $.ajax({
                    url:getData,
                    method:'get'
                }).done(function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    var markers_data = response 
                    $.each(resultData,function(i,value){
                        if((value.latitude!=0.0) || (value.longitude!=0.0)){
                            // Create the popup data if the response is in the same order as the markers_data
                            // If not use something like response[value.id]
                            var popup_data = markers_data[i] ? markers_data[i] : "no data"; 
                            L.marker([value.latitude,value.longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup(popup_data);
                        }
                    })
                })                              
            });
```